# Django/GraphQL triple join table

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating an app that allows users to answer form.

So I have :

```
class Form(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Question(models.Model):
    form = models.ForeignKey(Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Participation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    form = models.ForeignKey(Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Answer(models.Model):
    participation = models.ForeignKey(Participation)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

where `User` is a model from `django.contrib.auth.models`

**How can I query for all the users who have answered a specific form ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I query for all the users who have answered a specific form ?

If you have a specific `form` instance, you can get all the answers, where a user has participated and answered and from that get all the users:

```
users = Answer.objects.filter(participation__form=form).values('participation__user')
```

If you want to be extra cautious, you could check if the form in the question is same as the form in the participation:

```
users = Answer.objects.filter(participation__form=form,
                  question__form=form).values('participation__user')
```

Comment: Thanks ! Your technique return a list of ids, I then used `users = User.objects.filter(id__in=users_id)`

Comment: Yes, since it is a foreign key it will return a list of ids only.